# Number theory!Polynomial modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

From Fermats theorem we know that for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $$a^p\equiv a \mod{p}$$. But the polynomial $x^p$ it is not equal to the polynomial $x$( as a Congruence ). Why?Also when you want to solve a polynomial equation with modules you use that fermats theorem to simplify the polynomial.Doesnt that contradicts that  $x^p$ is not equal to $x$. SInce for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ $$a^p\equiv a \mod{p}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polynomial $x^2+x$ is always divisible by 2, but as polynomials $x^2+x\not\equiv0\pmod2$ -- for one thing, the degree on the left is different from the degree on the right.

Similarly, even though $x^p-x$ is zero mod $p$ for any $x$, *as polynomials*, $x^p$ and $x$ are different.

Basically "are equivalent as polynomials" is a fine-grained tool where "are equal at all integer $x$" is courser. If you know that $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are equivalent (mod $p$) as polynomials then you know that they take on the same value (mod $p$) for all integer $x$, but you can't conclude the converse.

Comment: So $$x^p\equiv x  modp$$ but as polynomials they differ since their coeficients are not the same modp

Comment: Yes. In $\mathbb{Z}$ you can say $x^p\equiv x\pmod p$ while in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ you have instead $x^p\not\equiv x\pmod p$.

Comment: (Two polynomials, i.e. members of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, are equivalent mod $p$ if and only if their coefficients (at every exponent) are congruent mod $p$.)

Comment: In $Z$ i can say they are equiv because for  $$x \in\ Z$$ they give the same value but their coeficients sill aint the same. in $Z$ i consider X as just a number not as an undefined variable like in $Z[x]$

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a distinction between (more concrete) functions from $\Bbb Z / p \Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$ and (more abstract) polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb Z/ p \Bbb Z$.

For each polynomial, there is an associated polynomial function. And as you have just discovered, it is NOT true that if the polynomial function is zero, then the polynomial is also zero.

On any finite ring $R$, you can make the polynomial $\prod_{x \in R} (X - x)$, whose polynomial function is obviously zero. But this polynomial is not zero !

Comment: Yes i understand that so you answer my second part about solving equations .The polynomial functions might have the same sollutions but the polynomials might differ.But why isnt x^p=xmod(p) ?

Comment: I don't understand your second part. Are you talking about polynomials or functions ?

Comment: We say that 2 polynomials are equivalent modp if and only  $$f(x)\equiv g(x)modp$$ for every x.But x^p is not equivalent modp  to x although if you use fermats theorem they are equivalent for every x.Does the author mean something else?

Comment: If you take this as your definition (which I find confusing because polynomials are not the same as polynomial functions), then by definition x^p is equivalent mod p to x because of Fermat's theorem. Does your definition say anything about the domain of x ? Because if you go into field extensions, there are some x for which x^p is not x. So this equivalence is not very well defined.

Comment: So for their polynomial functions they are equvilant?Maybe our teacher was just talking about the polynomial functions and in a book i saw that $x^p$ is not the same as $x$ my domain is $Z$

Comment: that's probably the case.

Answer (score 0):

Over the reals (or any infinite field), a polynomial induces the zero function iff it is the zero polynomial because a polynomial cannot have an infinite number of roots.

Things are different in finite fields. If the field has $q$ elements, then $X^{q}-X$ induces the zero function but is not the zero polynomial.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know the difference between Congruence Equation and Algebraic equation which obeys [Fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) unlike the previous one?

For example $$x^2\equiv2\pmod3$$ is not solvable unlike $$x^2=2$$

Again, $$a^p\equiv a\pmod p$$ is basically Identity Congruence Equation i.e., any integer satisfies this equation   just like $$\prod_{r=0}^{p-1}(x-r)\equiv0\pmod p$$

Comment: I mean that x^p=xmod(p) isnt that right?

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis, $'='$ should be replaced with $'\equiv'$